# How do I add a credit card number to another list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-mobile, form-submit

I have a collapsible form that asks for credit card info.  When someone clicks submit  I want the card number to be moved to another list.  How do I do this using Javascript.  This is my html:

```
<div class= "addStuff">
    <div data-role="collapsible" data-inset="true"  >
       <h5> New credit card</h5>         
          <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <input type="password" name="credit_card_number" id="credit_card_number" value="" placeholder="Credit Card Number">
            <input type="password" name="security_code" id="security_code" value="" placeholder="Security Code">
            <input type="date" name="expiration_date" id="expiration_date" value="" placeholder="Expiration Date">
            <input type="password" name="name" id="name" value="" placeholder="Name On Card">
            <input type="password" name="street_address" id="street_address" value="" placeholder="Street Address">
            <input type="text" name="city" id="city" value="" placeholder="City">
            <input type="number" name="zip_code" id="zip_code" value="" placeholder="Zip Code">
                <form action="accounts.html" method="post">
                <button type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" value="submit" data-theme="">Submit</button>
                </form>
          </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the list I want to add it to:

```
<div class="accounts">
<h2>Existing Acounts </h2>

<ul data-role="listview" >
        <div id= "Credit Cards">
    <li><a href="AccountDetails.html">BofA Enhcanced Checking 3212</a></li>
    <li><a href="AccountDetails.html">BankAmericard Platinum Plus Visa 4567</a></li>
    <li><a href="AccountDetails.html">CITI Platinum 4331</a></li>
        </div>
</ul>



<ul data-role="listview" >
        <div id= "Accounts">
    <li><a href="AccountDetails.html">Bank of America Checking</a></li>
    <li><a href="AccountDetails.html">Bank of America Savings</a></li>
        </div>
</ul>
```

And here is my attempt:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('.addStuff .submit').click(function(){
        $('#credit_card_number').addClass('.accounts' )
    });
});
```

Comment: I can't understand this question. What do you mean by "moved to another list" ? what list? i don't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change submit button to just be button:

```
<button type="button" class="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>`
```

Updated javascript is:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('.submit').click(function(){
        var creditcard = $('#credit_card_number').val();
        $("#CreditCards ul").append('<li><a href="AccountDetails.html">' + 
                creditcard + "</a></li>");

       // refresh view 
       $('#CreditCards ul').listview('refresh');

       // hide form 
       $('#ccdiv').trigger('collapse');
    }); 
 });​
```

Here is the working example: http://jsfiddle.net/donramos/aA7T8/2/

Comment: This one is working great.  The only problem I have is hiding the form with ` $('#ccdiv').trigger('collapse'); `  I basically copy and pasted your code and when the collapse didn't work I tried this:` $('[ data-role="collapsible"]').trigger('collapse'); `  Any ideas on gettin that to work?  Thanks so much.  The .append works great.

Comment: I suggest you add an id to the collapsible set, eg, ccdiv. Selectors using ids are more efficient and more readable.  See JSFiddle link above for details. Don't forget to accept "Answer", thanks.

Comment: Hi, one more thing, maybe change your title to something more generic and meaningful, eg "How do I dynamically add an item to a listview" since it would help others facing the same problem.  Just a suggestion :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('#oldForm .submit').click(function(){
        var option = $("#oldSelect option:selected");
        $("#newSelect").append('<option value='+option.val()+'>'+option.html()+'</option>');
    });
});
```

Comment: What would `#newSelect` and `#oldSelect` be?

Answer (score 0):

Have your list, for example:

```
<ul id="creditcards">
</ul>
```

Append the value of credit_card_number input into the list via jquery on button click:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('.submit').click(function(){
        $("#creditcards").append("<li>"+$("#credit_card_number").val()+"</li>");
    });
});
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/qC7BE/

Comment: This looks good, but it still doesn't work for some reason.  http://jsfiddle.net/QYCYP/

Comment: You had wrong jquery selector http://jsfiddle.net/QYCYP/2/ changed to use the class as in original question.